# Is there a way to force a mass refresh prices on old quotes in CPQ?

Tags: cpq, refresh

Rather than relying on the user to click the "Refresh Prices" button, is there a way that Admins can force a "Mass Refresh Prices" on older quotes?  We need to insert the new list price, because our integration sends the discount AMT, and we CALCULATE the discount amount, so we need to recalc the discount AMT based on a refreshed list price.  Any ideas?   We cannot rely on the users to use the button.

Comment: I haven't had time to test it, but it looks like CPQ has a class called `SBQQ.RefreshQuotePricesController` that has a global method called `onRefreshList` that takes a list of Ids. I wonder if you can call that method, passing in a list of quote ids to refresh.

Comment: I have tried to call SBQQ.RefreshQuotePricesController.onRefresh with a single SBQQ__Quote__c Id (as String) as an argument, but it didn't work. No error either. I did a manual refresh afterwards and it confirmed that the Quote Lines had not been refreshed. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The method mentioned in the comment by Daniel Hoechst does not seem to do anything, but it gave me the idea to look into the classes in the CPQ package. Not that you can inspect the complete contents, but the names and specifications of classes and methods are available.

It led me to the class QuotePriceRefreshBatch, which you can schedule:

```
System.scheduleBatch(new SBQQ.QuotePriceRefreshBatch(SBQQ__Quote__c.sObjectType,
    new Set<Id>{...}), 'Refresh quote', 1, 1);
```

where ... is a list of SBQQ__Quote__c ids.

I tested this and it works! It even sends you a mail after completion of the refresh.

Of course, this is completely undocumented and the method is not guaranteed to exist in future versions of CPQ.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318023&language=en_US&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1)

Basically create a checkbox and add it to the "Calculating Fields" fieldset on the SBQQ__Quote__c object.

Update this field and it will force the records to calculate.

Comment: While this will trigger recalculation, it doesn't refresh prices from the price book.